# Customize icon for jquerymobile collapsible item

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create a mobile page with jquerymobile collapsible for content display, and I also need customize the icon for each collapsible item in the list, look like http://m.box.net , an icon for login, for signup and so on.

Please give me any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

jQM Offers guidelines for Custom icons:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

> **Using 3rd party icon sets**
>  You can add any of the popular icon libraries like [Glyphish](http://glyphish.com/) to achieve the iOS style tab that
>   has large icons stacked on top of text labels. All that is required is
>   a bit of custom styles to link to the icons and position them in the
>   navbar. Here is an example using Glyphish icons and custom styles
>   (view page source for styles) in our navbar:

See jQM Page above for demo, here are the images below. You might not see them as they are white icons

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/

> Icons by Joseph Wain / [glyphish.com](http://glyphish.com/). Licensed under the [Creative
>   Commons Attribution 3.0 United States License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/us/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however with collapsible I cannot set a custom icon for each item, looks like in http://m.box.net